# android: how to handle taps on foreground notifications

Tags: android, react-native

I have a foreground Service that displays a persistent notification like so:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

  createNotificationChannel(); // Creating channel for API 26+
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);


  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
  Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("This is my service")
    .setContentText("Tap to open configuration")
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .build();
  startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

  return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Currently, tapping on this notification opens the app just like if I press the app icon. No extra info is passed. I need to tell if the app was opened from the notification and not from the app icon.

Now, [The docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation) say I can start some other activity, but my app is a React Native app, and I only have one real activity: `MainActivity`. The rest is in JS.

I'm assuming I need to create a BroadcastReceiver and somehow listen to intents that get sent while the user pushes the button. Or maybe I can handle intents in my `MainActivity` or some `Service` and emit events to JS from there. I am a bit lost. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add an extra flag to the notificationIntent like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);
```

Then you can retrieve that flag in `MainActivity.onCreate()` like this:

```
isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", false);
```

Also you may need to change the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.